# Tabs not rendering in accordion jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm using 2 jquery accordions with tabs inside them. It does work, but when I click on the 2nd accordion to expand it the 2 tabs inside are not rendering, but not sure why. Any help would be appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("button").button();    
$("#tabs").tabs();    
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
  collapsible: true
  }); 

});
</script>
</head>
<!--- The UI Part to EDIT -->
<body>
   <div id="accordion">
    <h3>SIRF</h3>
        <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <!--- TABS are Seperated by "li" -->
            <li><a href="#tab1">Info</a></li>        
            <li><a href="#tab2">Setup</a></li>
            <!-- <li><a href="#tab3"></a></li> -->        
            <li style="float:right;"><a href="#tab0">!</a></li>
        </ul>        
    </div>            
    <h3>TIRF</h3>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
            <!--- TABS are Seperated by "li" -->
            <li><a href="#tab3">Info</a></li>        
            <li><a href="#tab4">Setup</a></li>
            <!-- <li><a href="#tab3"></a></li> -->        
            <li style="float:right;"><a href="#tab0">!</a></li>
        </ul>

    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: Instead of editing the question with an answer, post an answer to your own question and then come back and accept it.

Comment: as a matter of fact, if you can find your own answer within 20 minutes of asking a question, there is a chance asking it in the first place was a bit lazy :p

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: Agreed. I was going to suggest deleting it but you never know who might stumble onto these types of questions.

Comment: If you've found an answer, post it as an answer; do not edit it into your question, please.

Comment: I actually did search for examples of others using accordion with nested tabs, but wasn't finding anything. I was going to delete my question since I solved it. But I figured I would leave in case someone else was having the same problem.

Comment: Spread the rep, accept an answer :) glad you were able to work it out yourself, always a good feeling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery is only acting on your first "tabs" div. Then when it's done it stops. You need to name them differently, and call `.tabs()` on both separately. **ID's in HTML must always be unique.**

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/9z8v3/) is a working fiddle

Answer (score 0):

After some searching and testing, I found that giving the different divs different IDs worked to solve the problem. Posted an answer about the same time as CDspace, which says basically the same thing.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("button").button();    
$("#tabs_a").tabs();   
$("#tabs_b").tabs();  
$( "#accordion" ).accordion({
      collapsible: true
      }); 

    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <!--- The UI Part to EDIT -->
    <body>
       <div id="accordion">
        <h3>SIRF</h3>
            <div id="tabs_a">id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <!--- TABS are Seperated by "li" -->
                <li><a href="#tab1">Info</a></li>        
                <li><a href="#tab2">Setup</a></li>
                <!-- <li><a href="#tab3"></a></li> -->        
                <li style="float:right;"><a href="#tab0">!</a></li>
            </ul>        
        </div>            
        <h3>TIRF</h3>
        <div id="tabs_b">id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <!--- TABS are Seperated by "li" -->
                <li><a href="#tab3">Info</a></li>        
                <li><a href="#tab4">Setup</a></li>
                <!-- <li><a href="#tab3"></a></li> -->        
                <li style="float:right;"><a href="#tab0">!</a></li>
            </ul>

        </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```